# Go Fish in Python

Tags: python

For my class i have to make a working Go fish game. i got this far in class but I'm stuck i cant figure out how send player back to Hand so i can make a check statement to see if he has any four of a kind. Any suggestions?

```
class Card(object):
    """ A playing card. """
    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
             "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    SUITS = ["c", "d", "h", "s"]

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank 
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return rep


class Hand(object):
    """ A hand of playing cards. """
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
           rep = ""
           for card in self.cards:
               rep += str(card) + "  "
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.cards = []

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)

    def check(self,player):
        print(player1)
        for self.cards in rep:
            print("i")
            #####################
class Deck(Hand):
    """ A deck of playing cards. """
    def populate(self):
        for suit in Card.SUITS:
            for rank in Card.RANKS: 
                self.add(Card(rank, suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, hands, per_hand = 1):
        for rounds in range(per_hand):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                    top_card = self.cards[0]
                    self.give(top_card, hand)
                else:
                    print ("Out of cards!")

def main():
    deck1 = Deck()
    deck1.populate()
    deck1.shuffle()
    player1 = Hand()
    player2 = Hand()
    hands = [player1, player2]
    deck1.deal(hands, per_hand = 5)
    print(player1)
    player1.check(player1)
main()
```

Comment: Seems like player is Hand. So why not just have the Hand check itself? Seem like you have the beginnings of doing that already (`check` never reference player). It's not very clear what your intention is for the `check` function. Should it return the best hand for those cards or should it figure out who is the winner out of the player or the other player passed in?

Answer (score 2):

What you said doesn't really make sense .  **Hand** is a class; **player1** is an instance of that class.  Translating into personal terms, this is parallel to asking how to send **Brandon** back to **human** so you can count his teeth.  You don't: you simply use the tooth-counting procedure that works on all humans.

Looking specifically at your code, I think this deals with the line

```
player1.check(player1)
```

All it should need is

```
player1.check()
```

**player1** is a **Hand**; this call goes to **Hand**'s **check** method.  Here, the object that invoked the method automatically shows up as the first argument, **self**.  Get rid of the second one and just use

```
def check(self):
```

Does that clarify the point of confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Check this code out, which is a working version of Go Fish executable and playable from the console. See how they use:

```
def makeTurn(self):
        print '%s\'s hand: %s' % (self.name,self.displayHand())
        chooseCard = raw_input('What card do you ask for? ').strip()
        if chooseCard == 'quit':
            sys.exit(0)
        if chooseCard not in self.hand:
            print 'You don\'t have that card. Try again! (or enter quit to exit)'
            chooseCard = self.makeTurn()
        return chooseCard
```

Here is the complete [Python Go Fish game](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Go_Fish/Python).

```
import random
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

class HumanPlayer(object):
    def __init__(self,deck):
        self.hand = defaultdict(int)
        self.book = []
        self.deck = deck #making a copy of deck, all changes within
                        #this class should affect the global deck
        self.score = 0
        self.name = raw_input('Name yourself: ')

    def Draw(self): #assuming that deck is a global
        cardDrawn = self.deck.pop() #removes the last card from deck
        self.hand[cardDrawn] += 1 #adds card to hand
        print '%s drew %s.' % (self.name,cardDrawn)
        self.checkForBooks()

    def checkForBooks(self):
#       Removes all items of which are 4.
        for key,val in self.hand.items(): #can't use iteritems() because we are modifying hand in loop
            if val == 4: #completed a book
                self.book.append(key)
                print '%s completed the book of %s\'s.' % (self.name,key)
                self.score += 1
                del self.hand[key]
        self.emptyCheck()

    def emptyCheck(self):
        if len(self.deck)!=0 and len(self.hand)==0: #checks if deck/hand is empty
            self.Draw()
    def displayHand(self): #Displays current hand, cards separated by spaces
        return ' '.join(key for key,val in self.hand.iteritems()
                        for i in range(val)) #meh, make it prettier

    def makeTurn(self):
        print '%s\'s hand: %s' % (self.name,self.displayHand())
        chooseCard = raw_input('What card do you ask for? ').strip()
        if chooseCard == 'quit':
            sys.exit(0)
        if chooseCard not in self.hand:
            print 'You don\'t have that card. Try again! (or enter quit to exit)'
            chooseCard = self.makeTurn()
        return chooseCard

    def fishFor(self,card):
        if card in self.hand: # if card in hand, returns count and removes the card from hand
            val = self.hand.pop(card)
            self.emptyCheck()
            return val
        else:
            return False
    def gotCard(self,card,amount):
        self.hand[card] += amount
        self.checkForBooks()



class Computer(HumanPlayer):
    def __init__(self,deck):
        self.name = 'Computer'
        self.hand = defaultdict(int)
        self.book = []
        self.deck = deck
        self.opponentHas = set()
        self.score = 0

    def Draw(self): #assuming that deck is a global
        cardDrawn = self.deck.pop() #removes the last card from deck
        self.hand[cardDrawn] += 1 #adds card to hand
        print '%s drew a card.' % (self.name)
        self.checkForBooks()

    ##AI: guesses cards that knows you have, then tries cards he has at random.
    ##Improvements: remember if the card was rejected before, guess probabilities
    def makeTurn(self):
#        print self.displayHand(),self.opponentHas
        candidates = list(self.opponentHas & set(self.hand.keys())) #checks for cards in hand that computer knows you have
        if not candidates:
            candidates = self.hand.keys() #if no intersection between those two, random guess
        move = random.choice(candidates)
        print '%s fishes for %s.' % (self.name,move)
        return move

    def fishFor(self,card): #Same as for humans players, but adds the card fished for to opponentHas list.
        self.opponentHas.add(card)
        if card in self.hand: # if card in hand, returns count and removes the card from hand
            val = self.hand.pop(card)
            self.emptyCheck()
            return val
        else:
            return False

    def gotCard(self,card,amount):
        self.hand[card] += amount
        self.opponentHas.discard(card)
        self.checkForBooks()

class PlayGoFish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = ('2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A '*4).split(' ')
        self.deck.remove('')
        self.player = [HumanPlayer(self.deck),Computer(self.deck)] #makes counting turns easier

    def endOfPlayCheck(self):#checks if hands/decks are empty using the any method
            return self.deck or self.player[0].hand or self.player[1].hand

    def play(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)
        for i in xrange(9): # Deal the first cards
            self.player[0].Draw()
            self.player[1].Draw()
        turn = 0
        while self.endOfPlayCheck():
            print '\nTurn %d (%s:%d %s:%d) %d cards remaining.' % (turn,self.player[0].name,
                    self.player[0].score,self.player[1].name,self.player[1].score,len(self.deck))
            whoseTurn = turn%2
            otherPlayer = (turn+1)%2
            while True: #loop until player finishes turn
                cardFished = self.player[whoseTurn].makeTurn()
                result = self.player[otherPlayer].fishFor(cardFished)
                if not result: #Draws and ends turn
                    self.player[whoseTurn].Draw()
                    break
                print '%s got %d more %s.' % (self.player[whoseTurn].name,result, cardFished)
                self.player[whoseTurn].gotCard(cardFished,result)
                if not self.endOfPlayCheck(): break
            turn+=1
        print '\nScores: \n%s: %d\n%s: %d\n' % (self.player[0].name,self.player[0].score,
                                          self.player[1].name,self.player[1].score)
        if self.player[0].score>self.player[1].score:
            print self.player[0].name,'won!'
        elif self.player[0].score==self.player[1].score:
            print 'Draw!'
        else:
            print self.player[1].name,'won!'

if __name__=="__main__":
    game = PlayGoFish()
    game.play()
```

Comment: It''s a shame that you've just thrown away the poster's homework assignment by giving them a full, copy/paste example of someone else's work. I hope that your entire office becomes filled with coders who have learned by copy/pasting from SO instead of learning by doing their own work, so that you get to support them and do their work for them in the future.